# Separate where in query

Tags: postgresql, go, where-clause, go-gorm

I need to separate `where` to validates values with conditional, Example

```
email := "test@test.com"
if email != "" {
  db.Where("users.email LIKE ?", "%"+email+"%")
}
db.Where("users.name like ?", "%"+jhon+"%").Find(&users)
```

That returns two queries:

1: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE users.email LIKE '%test@test.com%'`

2: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE users.name LIKE '%jhon%'`

but I need the result in only one query:

```
 SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE users.email LIKE '%test@test.com%' and users.name LIKE '%jhon%'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
chain := db.Where("users.name like ?", "%"+jhon+"%")
email := "test@test.com"
if email != "" {
  chain = chain.Where("users.email LIKE ?", "%"+email+"%")
}
chain.Find(&users)
```

All of the Gorm methods like `Where` return a result, which is chainable. That means that you can continue calling methods on it until you get something that you like.

Comment: Add `chain := db.Where("")` ahead may be better.

Comment: What about postgresql? The placeholder is '$1', '$2'... instead of '?'